# How to do history.go(-2) with hrad refresh in javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I want to reload my WordPress page when user login to previous URL from where they are traveling to login page, this code seems to do the Job, but it reloads previous state of data(loads data stored in browser). I want to hard reload the page with history.go(-2).

```
function login_register_redirect()
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    history.go(-2);
    </script>";
}
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'login_register_redirect', 99);
add_filter('woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'login_register_redirect', 99);
```

Comment: Is there anyone who can help on this problem?

Comment: Just asking if someone facing same issue, or have any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP to get the referring URL.
Pass this URL to a JavaScript function that will redirect the browser to this URL with a hard reload.

Function goes to active theme function file

```
function login_register_redirect() {
    // Check if HTTP_REFERER is set
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
        // Get the referring URL
        $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

        // Use JavaScript to redirect and force a hard reload
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                window.location.href = '" . esc_js($referrer) . "';
              </script>";
    } else {
        // Default redirect if HTTP_REFERER is not set
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                window.location.href = '" . esc_js(get_home_url()) . "';
              </script>";
    }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'login_register_redirect', 99);
add_filter('woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'login_register_redirect', 99);
```

Comment: Thanks, for your code, i have resolved it now with help of plugin.